# Python3 - Add element from list, but do not add if it is already there

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read done.txt add it to a list and add the last two index to file index.html after `"<tr>"` or between `<tr>` and `</tr>` but I do not want to add anything if the last two index are already in index.html...

Also, everytime I execute the python script, it add new line to the entire file. how can I stop this? I am noob trying to learn. Love yall.

```
import fileinput
with open('done.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print(myNames)
    for line in fileinput.FileInput("index.html", inplace=1):
        if "<tr>" in line:
            if myNames[-1] not in line:
                line = line.replace(line, line + "<th>" + myNames[-1] + "<th>" + "\n")
            elif myNames[-2] not in line:
                line = line.replace(line, line + "<th>" + myNames[-2] + "<th>" + "\n")
        print (line)
```